# Slipping motion using KinematicBody2D?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to simulate an ice floor for my character but I can't figure out how to achieve that using `kinematicBody2D`

this is my player script:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    direction.y += gravity_speed * delta
    
    # vertical movement
    if(is_on_floor()):
        if(Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up")):
            direction.y=jump_speed
    
    # horizontal movement
    direction.x=Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    direction.x *= horizontal_speed
    
    direction=move_and_slide(direction,Vector2.UP)
```

and I made a `StaticBody2D` and gave it 0 friction in physics material override:

[image]

And it seems to work with Rigid bodies but not with `KinematicBody2D`,
I thought `move_and_slide()` should take care of this?

So how do I get my character to slip on certain grounds?

Comment: A physics material won't affect a KinematicBody2D because KinematicBody2D is not affected by physics - see the documentation:https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html

To simulate sliding, you will need to perform some kind of interpolation of your `direction` value so that it is not immediately applied but rather gradually applied to your character.  Then, you will also need to interpolate from velocity to 0 when the user is not providing input.